How to use Depends and Path at the same time in FastAPI?
I have the following endpoint:
@router.get('/events/{base_id}')
def asd(base_id: common_input_types.event_id) -> None:
    do_something()

And this is common_input_types.event_id:
event_id = Annotated[
    int,
    fastapi.Depends(dependency_function),
    fastapi.Path(
        example=123,
        description="Lore",
        gt=5,
        le=100,
    ),
]

This does not trigger the dependency function. When I remove the fastapi.Path part, it works. But then I won't have the example and the min-max in swagger.
How do I specify both?

What is the reason to do so? Do you want to use default value from Path, but have the ability to override it in dependency_function on some condition?

I want to have the example value and the gt and le in swagger. Also, I want to have a dependency function. Apparently both at the same time is not so easily possible.

I don't think it's possible to annotate a parameter with Path and Depends at the same time.
Depending on the logic you want to implement, you can move this logic to dependency_function:
from typing import Annotated
import fastapi

app = fastapi.FastAPI()

router = fastapi.APIRouter(prefix="")


async def dependency_function(
    base_id: Annotated[
        int, fastapi.Path(example=123, description="Lore", gt=5, le=100)
    ]
):
    some_condition = True
    if some_condition:
        return 123
    else:
        return base_id


@router.get('/events/{base_id}')
def asd(base_id: Annotated[int, fastapi.Depends(dependency_function)]) -> None:
    print(base_id)

app.include_router(router)


That works, thanks!
